# Python function not working inside another function when calling it

Tags: python, function, data-conversion

When I attempt to call the menu function in each choice after the conversion is run, it will take me back to the menu but will only convert in the original selection. If I choose option 1 first after the convertCelsius function is ran and it takes me back to the menu function, any choice will still only convert to celsius. How do I get call the menu function so I can run each choice again.

```
def menu():
    print("1. Celsius to Fahrenheit")
    print('2. Fahrenheit to Celsius')
    print('3. Exit')
    pick = int(input('Enter a choice: '))
    return pick

def convertCelsius():
    temperature = float(input('Write temp to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit: '))
    fahrenheitTemperature = ((temperature * 1.8) + 32)
    print('Fahrenheit temperature is: ',fahrenheitTemperature)
def convertFahrenheit():
        temperature = float(input('Write tempt to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius: '))
        celsiusTemperature = ((temperature - 32)* 5/9)
        print("Celsius temperature is: ", celsiusTemperature)

def main():
    choice = menu()
    while choice != 3:
        if choice == 1:
           convertCelsius()
           menu()
        elif choice == 2:
            convertFahrenheit()
            menu()
        elif choice==3:
           choice = menu()
main()
```

Comment: You never update `choice` afer entering the loop. You should do `choice = menu()` each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do `choice = menu()` every time:

```py
def main():
    choice = menu()
    while choice != 3:
        if choice == 1:
           convertCelsius()
        elif choice == 2:
            convertFahrenheit()
        choice = menu()
```